# Spring bean destroyMethod

Tags: spring

Looking at the code below, the destroy method is "close" and this method only available in the implementation class of javax.sql.DataSource (HikariDataSource) but not in javax.sql.DataSource.

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    return (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/abc");
}
```

Does Spring able to call the close method above or I need to redefine the Bean Java config to return an implementation class as below?

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public HikariDataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    return (HikariDataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/abc");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the datasource through a JNDI lookup it is a shared resource configured in your container. And it's that container's job to manage the lifecycle of the datasource. Spring just makes use of it, so it is not required to close it. I would recommend to configure it like this:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    return (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/abc");
}
```